# Why I can't connect to online sql db with sequelize

Tags: mysql, node.js, sequelize.js

I try to learn about API and try to connect API to SQL database. I try some code online (from github: https://github.com/cornflourblue/node-mysql-registration-login-api.git) and it works just fine in localhost. But when I try the online database with freedb.tech, I got:

```
          throw new SequelizeErrors.AccessDeniedError(err);
AccessDeniedError [SequelizeAccessDeniedError]: Access denied for user 'freedb_moruuser'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
    at ConnectionManager.connect (C:\Users\Agung Suhermin\Documents\Code\attacktest\nodelearn-jasonwatmore\node-mysql-registration-login-api\node_modules\sequelize\lib\dialects\mysql\connection-manager.js:118:17)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
    at async ConnectionManager._connect (C:\Users\Agung Suhermin\Documents\Code\attacktest\nodelearn-jasonwatmore\node-mysql-registration-login-api\node_modules\sequelize\lib\dialects\abstract\connection-manager.js:318:24)
    at async C:\Users\Agung Suhermin\Documents\Code\attacktest\nodelearn-jasonwatmore\node-mysql-registration-login-api\node_modules\sequelize\lib\dialects\abstract\connection-manager.js:250:32
    at async ConnectionManager.getConnection (C:\Users\Agung Suhermin\Documents\Code\attacktest\nodelearn-jasonwatmore\node-mysql-registration-login-api\node_modules\sequelize\lib\dialects\abstract\connection-manager.js:280:7)
    at async C:\Users\Agung Suhermin\Documents\Code\attacktest\nodelearn-jasonwatmore\node-mysql-registration-login-api\node_modules\sequelize\lib\sequelize.js:613:26
    at async MySQLQueryInterface.createTable (C:\Users\Agung Suhermin\Documents\Code\attacktest\nodelearn-jasonwatmore\node-mysql-registration-login-api\node_modules\sequelize\lib\dialects\abstract\query-interface.js:225:12)
    at async Function.sync (C:\Users\Agung Suhermin\Documents\Code\attacktest\nodelearn-jasonwatmore\node-mysql-registration-login-api\node_modules\sequelize\lib\model.js:1300:5)
    at async Sequelize.sync (C:\Users\Agung Suhermin\Documents\Code\attacktest\nodelearn-jasonwatmore\node-mysql-registration-login-api\node_modules\sequelize\lib\sequelize.js:793:35)
    at async initialize (C:\Users\Agung Suhermin\Documents\Code\attacktest\nodelearn-jasonwatmore\node-mysql-registration-login-api\_helpers\db.js:27:5) {
  parent: Error: Access denied for user 'freedb_moruuser'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
      at Packet.asError (C:\Users\Agung Suhermin\Documents\Code\attacktest\nodelearn-jasonwatmore\node-mysql-registration-login-api\node_modules\mysql2\lib\packets\packet.js:712:17)
      at ClientHandshake.execute (C:\Users\Agung Suhermin\Documents\Code\attacktest\nodelearn-jasonwatmore\node-mysql-registration-login-api\node_modules\mysql2\lib\commands\command.js:28:26)
      at Connection.handlePacket (C:\Users\Agung Suhermin\Documents\Code\attacktest\nodelearn-jasonwatmore\node-mysql-registration-login-api\node_modules\mysql2\lib\connection.js:417:32)
      at PacketParser.onPacket (C:\Users\Agung Suhermin\Documents\Code\attacktest\nodelearn-jasonwatmore\node-mysql-registration-login-api\node_modules\mysql2\lib\connection.js:75:12)
      at PacketParser.executeStart (C:\Users\Agung Suhermin\Documents\Code\attacktest\nodelearn-jasonwatmore\node-mysql-registration-login-api\node_modules\mysql2\lib\packet_parser.js:75:16)
      at Socket.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Agung Suhermin\Documents\Code\attacktest\nodelearn-jasonwatmore\node-mysql-registration-login-api\node_modules\mysql2\lib\connection.js:82:25)
      at Socket.emit (node:events:513:28)
      at addChunk (node:internal/streams/readable:315:12)
      at readableAddChunk (node:internal/streams/readable:289:9)
      at Socket.Readable.push (node:internal/streams/readable:228:10) {
      at Socket.emit (node:events:513:28)
      at addChunk (node:internal/streams/readable:315:12)
      at readableAddChunk (node:internal/streams/readable:289:9)
      at Socket.Readable.push (node:internal/streams/readable:228:10) { 
    code: 'ER_ACCESS_DENIED_ERROR',
    errno: 1045,
    sqlState: '28000',
    sqlMessage: "Access denied for user 'freedb_moruuser'@'localhost' (using password: YES)"
```

I already try to use this freedb to try a simple mysql connection and it works just fine, but when I try code with Sequelize, it breaks. The code look like this:

```
const config = require('config.json');
const mysql = require('mysql2/promise');
const { Sequelize } = require('sequelize');

module.exports = db = {};

initialize();

async function initialize() {
    // create db if it doesn't already exist
    const { host, port, user, password, database } = config.database;
    const connection = await mysql.createConnection({ host, port, user, password });
    await connection.query(`CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS \`${database}\`;`);

    // connect to db
    const sequelize = new Sequelize(database, user, password, { dialect: 'mysql' });

    // init models and add them to the exported db object
    db.User = require('../users/user.model')(sequelize);

    // sync all models with database
    await sequelize.sync();
}
```

And i set the database config like this:

```
{
    "database": {
        "host": "sql.freedb.tech",
        "port": 3306,
        "user": "freedb_moruuser",
        "password": "F%#!7Bdja*V?48A",
        "database": "freedb_MoruDatabase"
    },
    "secret": "THIS IS USED TO SIGN AND VERIFY JWT TOKENS, REPLACE IT WITH YOUR OWN SECRET, IT CAN BE ANY STRING"
}
```

So why can't i connect? Is it because i use mysql2 in my code but freedb.tech use mysql8? or is it something else?
[i have tried to use mysql instead of mysql2 but it's not working]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So first i tried with different version of mysql and still failed, but when i use pool instead of directly creating connection, it worked